# How can i get the list indices from nested lists whilst checking the contents of the list cell?

Tags: python, matrix, iteration, layer, enumerate

basically I'm making an ascii turn based game that uses a grid. I want to be able to make a second grid or 'layer' that holds data about that cell and has a direct relationship to the first grid through sharing the same index values. While i have achieved some working results in a previous build of my game, even in that i got stuck because I couldn't figure out how to get the list indices.

Now I've found out that I can get the indices by using the inumerate() function. Below is a practice
program I tried:

```
    #some example lists
    list = [[0, 2],[2, 3], [9,4], [5, 9]]
    list2 =[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0]]

    # a for loop to iterate through all elements of the nested list
    # using enumerate to to gain access to the list indices

    for i, j in enumerate(list):
        for ii, jj in enumerate(list):

            # if statements below seemingly not working.
            # jj is supposed to hold the contents of the current list cell
            # also when the 'else' kicks in because jj didn't match anything 
            # throws an error index out of range

            if jj == 0:
                list2[i][ii] = 'A'
            elif jj == 2:
                list2[i][ii] = 'C'
            else:
                list2[i][ii] = 1
        print(i, ii)
        print(jj)
    for i in list2:
        print(i)
```

The program doesn't work, (I commented about the errors I get in the code above) and I'd like to know how I can get it to work. Thanks a lot for your time and patience.

Comment: By `for i, j in enumerate(list)` I think you mean `for i, j in enumerate(list2)`. And by `for ii, jj in enumerate(list)` I think you mean `for ii, jj in enumerate(j)`.

Comment: I think you mean `for ii, jj in enumerate(j)`

Comment: @aecolley I think both you and @ inspectorG4dget when you say i should have `for ii, jj in enumerate(j)` rather than (list), but list2 is the list i hope to alter depending on what's in the first list using ii to keep track of the indices, so i don't know why i would enumerate over it. but yes, changing the second enumerate to (j) made the code work as expected thank you both very much!

Comment: Perhaps you want to enumerate(list) in the outer loop, and enumerate(list2[i]) in the inner loop?

Comment: Also, it's a horrible idea to name a variable `list` or `file` or `dict`. Avoid naming variables to share names with python data structures

Comment: @aecolley I'm not sure why you're suggesting that. Changing the second enumerate(list) to enumerate(j) worked perfectly.

inspectorG4dget -  yeah totally, thanks for the tip but I only used it for this little program so i could try and work out how to get the function doing what I needed. I don't habitually use generic variable names - thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: Do yourself (and us) a favor and in the future use more descriptive variable names. IT's somewhat of a convention to use `for idx, val` or  `for index, value` when using enumerate.

Comment: @IanAuld Thanks - I wasn't aware of the conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. DO NOT use name of built-in function as name of your variable.
2. Use meaningful variable name instead of meaningless ones, like ii, jj, which will make your code hard to read

I think you want to assign new values to the second list according to values of first list. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-


#some example myLists
myList = [[0, 2],[2, 3], [9,4], [5, 9]]
myList2 =[[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0],[0, 0]]

for index0, value0 in enumerate(myList):

    for index1, value1 in enumerate(value0):

        if value1 == 0:
            myList2[index0][index1] = 'A'
        elif value1 == 2:
            myList2[index0][index1] = 'C'
        else:
            myList2[index0][index1] = 'else'

print myList2
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since every cell in both lists will be visited, and since the indices of each directly map (0 in list maps to 0 in list2), the current index is implied and a list comprehension can be used.

```
grid = [[0, 2], [2, 3], [9, 4], [5, 9]]
mapping = {0: 'A', 2: 'C'}
grid2 = [[mapping.get(cell, 1) for cell in row] for row in grid]
```